# Audit Trail: profile updated

Tags: permissions, setup-audit-log

can some one please help me understand an audit trail log, there is a row that I can not understand. In short I was investigating why one of our profiles got changed, and found this line in the audit file:

Date: 5/17/2021 3:31:34 PM EDT

User: salesforce.com, inc.

Action: Changed Profile Integration: Enabled Contact permission because EntitlementContact has already been enabled.

What does it mean user "salesforce.com, inc."? could it be an update from salesforce of some sort?  and why would it change EntitlementContact object. I am not even sure what this object does.

Comment: This **seems** to be done as part of their Summer'21 release, where they have enabled more modular licensing(permission set licensing). 

You can check those license on user,permission set license assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided these Audit Trial changes are due to DB scripts that are automated in the background for limits provisioning and it technically appears that some org features have been checked. These changes do not impact your org or org limits and nothing to worry about it.

From [EntitlementContact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitlementcontact.htm) Id of contact is required to associate with entitlement.

Thanks